# processing parquet file in pyspark on saving giving error

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am doing a process using csv files like this

```
df = spark.read.csv(path = '/mycsv.csv', header = True)
```

then saving to db

```
%sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MY_DB
```

and

```
df.write.saveAsTable("MY_DB.mycsv")
```

it's working fine

now In case of parquet I am doing somehow same

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(path = '/sample.parquet', header = True)
```

then

```
df.write.saveAsTable("MY_DB.sample")
```

and it's giving me error

**AnalysisException**

```
AnalysisException: 
Found invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=" in the column names of your
schema. 
Please enable column mapping by setting table property 'delta.columnMapping.mode' to 'name'.

For more details, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/delta-column-mapping
Or you can use alias to rename it.
```

what it means ?

**UPDATE**

on print schema on parquet file it is showing

```
root
 |-- Region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sales Channel/test: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Order Priority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Order Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Order ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Ship Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Units Sold: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Unit Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Unit Cost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Revenue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Cost: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Profit: double (nullable = true)
```

and for csv file it is showing (it is diff file and parquet is diff file)

```
root
 |-- HashKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GLKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AccountingDateKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MainAccountKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LocationKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BusinessUnitKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DepartmentKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CompanyKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialHierarchyKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialSLIDKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialTaxKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialPayrollKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialCustomerKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialVendorKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialBankKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialInventoryKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialIntangiblesKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialBankSubKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DimGLKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DWCreatedDateTime: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: can you attach the output of `df.printSchema()` of both the csv and the parquet?

Comment: @MohamedYasser after reading the file ?

Comment: Yes. Read the csv and call `printSchema()` , read the parquet and call `printSchema()` again, attach both outputs to the question if possible.

Comment: @MohamedYasser question updated

Comment: The error says `Found invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=" in the column names of your schema. ` Notice that the first invalid character it mentions is the whitespace. The CSV file is well-named, the parquet however isn't. Many databases will reject column names that have whitespace. You can use allowed characters to separate the words, like a dash or an underscore instead of whitespace. For example, instead of `Unit Cost` rename it to `UnitCost` or `Unit_Cost`. You can do so by calling `.withColumnRenamed("Unit Cost","UnitCost")` on the dataframe.

Comment: @MohamedYasser so issue is with parquet file column names , is there any way to remove spaces in column name from all columns before saving in database ?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the names of the columns contain whitespace. The option I got is that you rename the columns using `.withColumnRenamed()` method as I mentioned in the previous comment. However, If you want a way to let pyspark/databricks map the whitespace to another character or bulk-rename the columns, then that's a different question and I would suggest you close this one and open another one. Before opening another question, read the link attached with the exception and try to google if someone asked the same question before.

Comment: I think you should answer this question and accept the answer to mark the question as answered. The link provides a way to allow the invalid characters `" ,;{}()\n\t="` in the table name, try it. If that doesn't work then google it, if that fails too then open another question.

Comment: @MohamedYasser thanks . answered with solution . thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a  issue in columns name which were creating issue . after using select in conjunction with a list comprehension it should now returning name of columns as Item_Type

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

renamed_df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(col.replace(' ', '_')) for col in df.columns])
```